# Flutter image Grid maker app for Instagram post?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

#### [Example App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.techpositive.photosplit&hl=en_IN&gl=US)

Main Task is:- Single image to grid images(Split single image into multiple images) get Any Solution and any source if available then added to reply.

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about stacking a white grid over the image ?

Comment: Nope. I have a single image and I want to convert it into Grid. So Basically First I edit an image in the app after converting the widget into a png image then I want small parts of images like the above you can refer example app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the image package

https://pub.dev/packages/image

Then taking the reference of the width of the image you can split it into 9 blocks diving it by 3. Then convert the list to image again

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: ImageSplitter());
  }
}

class ImageSplitter extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageSplitter({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ImageSplitter> createState() => _ImageSplitterState();
}

class _ImageSplitterState extends State<ImageSplitter> {
  List<Image> imageList = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            MaterialButton(
              child: Text("Convert"),
              onPressed: () async {
                String imageUrl =
                    "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/3jwl-Nx7p2AuC64DHHZN3tTbMtpgPWQGHsVZmgDcFWRQoKkXg0n8g2P8DuYT4Ck5wUtk";
                Uint8List bytes = (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
                        .load(imageUrl))
                    .buffer
                    .asUint8List();
                imageList = splitImage(bytes);
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
            Wrap(
              children: List.generate(
                  imageList.length,
                  (index) => Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      child: imageList[index])),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<Image> splitImage(List<int> input) {
  // convert image to image from image package
  img.Image? image = img.decodeImage(input);

  int x = 0, y = 0;
  int width = (image!.width / 3).round();
  int height = (image.height / 3).round();

  // split image to parts
  List<img.Image> parts = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      parts.add(img.copyCrop(image, x, y, width, height));
      x += width;
    }
    x = 0;
    y += height;
  }

  // convert image from image package to Image Widget to display
  List<Image> _imageList = [];
  for (var singlePart in parts) {
    _imageList.add(Image.memory(img.encodeCur(singlePart) as Uint8List));
  }

  return _imageList;
}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: I am using an image picker so I am not using network image how to convert file image to unit8list image.

Comment: In case of local image instead of network bundle use root bundle

Comment: Any suggestion about save this parts into gallery please guide me.